# EEG topography from basic

Tags: c#, topography

I am trying to develope a program that can draw this picture based on user input.
https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_plot_topographical_map_of_scalp_from_EEG_data

I am trying to use c# from Visual Studio 2017 to write this program.

I had searched on the net, but it only show me the product instead of coding.

I realized Matlab, Ilnumberics, VTK can do this.

The issue of Ilnumberics and VTK is, i need to install them just for a little function from them. I don't think this is a good solution.

Would like to ask, is there any suggestion for me.

Thank you.

Comment: The generic name for such a graph is "heatmap".  So google "c# heatmap" to find solutions, lotsa hits.  Nothing wrong with a product if you have no idea whatsoever how to implement this btw.

Comment: @HansPassant thank for the replay. Will try and see.